# How to automatically create rows in an HTML table by populating data taken from a DB

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, html-table

Hi all I have a table of a database in MYSQL containing many lines called  "mezziDiTrasporto".
My goal is to create a table that once the SELECT is performed on the table, automatically generate rows populated by the data extracted from my DB table
Is it possible to do all this?

```html
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td  style="vertical-align: middle;" align="center">SI/NO</br><input  type="checkbox" class="chkView"/></td>
     <td bgcolor="#DCDCDC"><input type="text" name="idMezzo" id="idMezzo" width="75px" class="chkEdit" enable></td>
    
     <td><form action="">
   <select name="mezziDiTrasporto" class="chkEdit" enable>
     <optgroup label="1 - Mezzi d'opera">
      <option value="http://www.html.it">Escavatore</option>
      <option value="http://www.html.it/javascript">Terna</option>
      <option value="http://www.html.it/css">Pala</option>
      <option value="http://www.html.it/css">Autobenpompa</option>
    
       </optgroup>
 
     <optgroup label="2 - Automezzi">
      <option value="http://font.html.it">Camion</option>
      <option value="http://cgipoint.html.it">Autovetture </option>
      <option value="http://www.html.it/css">Autocarro</option>
      <option value="http://www.html.it/css">Furgoni</option>
     </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="3 - Mezzi di sollevamento (All. VII del D-Lgs. 81/08)">
      <option value="http://font.html.it">Gru</option>
      <option value="http://cgipoint.html.it">CamionGru </option>
      <option value="http://www.html.it/css">AutoGru</option>
      <option value="http://www.html.it/css">PLE</option>
     </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="4 - Attrezzature">
      <option value="http://font.html.it">Trapani</option>
      <option value="http://cgipoint.html.it">Sega Circolare</option>
      <option value="http://www.html.it/css">Martelli demolitori</option>
      <option value="http://www.html.it/css">Trabatelli</option>
     </optgroup>
   
 </select>
</form> </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="id7" id="id8" width="75px" class="chkEdit" enable></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="id8" id="id9" width="75px" class="chkEdit" enable></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="id9" id="id10" width="75px" class="chkEdit" enable></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="id10" id="id11" width="75px" class="chkEdit" enable></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">
   <p>Carica file </p>
   <p></p>

   <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div>
</td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Upload file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file" >

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable >

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable> 

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td><div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">

    <div id="drag_upload_file">

        <p>Carica file </p>

        <p></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" class="chkEdit" enable></p>

        <input type="file" id="selectfile" class="chkEdit" enable>

    </div>

</div></td>
     <td></td>
     <td width="144" bgcolor="#6DFD1E">AUTORIZZATO    /<br>
       NON AUTORIZZATO</td>
     <td width="138">SI se Y e AB    sono OK e AA Foglio Aut. Sub.</td>
     <td>Scarica Badge mezzo</td>
     <td width="165">Se SI, stampa    badge con data autorizzazione dalla Casella AC58 foglio Aut. Singolo Sub</td>
      </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Below I post a screenshot of my HTML table that I have to become dynamic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onsCY.png)

My question is: Can I create a function that will add so many rows (`<tr>`) of the table how many rows are in the database? 
Is there already a premade function that performs this task?
Asked this question because I have no idea how to develop the code for this function.

Comment: Please post some code, What did you already try

Comment: I asked this question because I have no idea how to develop the code for this function. @Mike

Comment: Atleast you could show us your table structure, html code.

Comment: Okay I'll add them, but keep in mind that there are thousands of lines of code @Mike

Comment: Well it's not really necessary to post double code.

Comment: there is no premade function for doing this task , you have to do it manually. So what you can do is like create a table in HTML and then get your data from database ( may be via ajax) and then do a loop through it and inject the data to the dynamic row ( you can go with static hardcoded <tr>your td infi<t/r> for this ) and append those tr to your table using the id of table

Comment: Oh damn, I don't think I live up to that function:(
Would you be so kind as to make an example even very simple so that I then re the whole? @ArunprasanthKV

Comment: provided a general example please have a look into that

Answer (score 0):

@Andrea Pilenga. 
Do let me know if any of the following steps you want me to eloborate.

Steps to populate your table dynamically with the data selected from the database:

1) Fetch the records from the database in a php array variable, $records.
2) In PHP File, also create a function generateRows() and pass $records as a parameter to it. The generateRows() function would look somewhat as follows:

```
function generateRows($records)
{
   $html = "";

   foreach($records as $row)
   {
      $html .= "<tr><td>$row['".column1."']</td><td>$row['".column2."']</td><td>$row['".columnn."']</td></tr>"; 
   }
   return $html;
}
```

Call the above function just below you have defined your header row of html table inside php tag ().

Let me know if not understood anything or need some eloboration.

Comment: Why making a separate function for it? Why not just the foreach?

Comment: @Mike. So that it could be used as the reusable component and will help in keeping the code loosely coupled. It is not compulsion but a good practice.

Comment: @VrajeshDoshi I'm really grateful for your kind response.. But do you say that this line `$html .= "<tr><td>$row['".column1."']</td><td>$row['".column2."']</td><td>$row['".columnn."']</td></tr>";`  still works despite the attractiveness of my table?

Comment: @AndreaPilenga it will not works despite the attractiveness of your table , but it will answer your question. We cannot provide the who;e code for you. We can only help you where you are stuck.

Comment: No mate, I was not asking you the solution to my problem.. It was just a question however now I do my trying.. Thank you both for the Help

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no predefined method for creating tables from a dataset in pure JavaScript So We have to write our own logic for doing the same.

The information you have provided is insufficient for creating a perfect working sample

As in general You can follow the below steps to create table based on database results

Step 1 : Create an ajax request to your server side method for getting the database data.

Step 2 : Get the data in Ajax success

Step 3 : Loop through the data and create a Dynamic tr with td values from the data set

Step 4 : Append the tr to your table using table Id.

Example : 
Html

```
<span>JSON:</span>
<pre id="json"></pre>
<input type="button" id="btnConvert" value="Convert To Table" />
```

Javascript

```
var jData = '[{"fname":"Mark", "lname":"Wood", "company":"Apple"},' +
  '{"fname":"Steve", "lname":"Jones", "company":"Amazon"},' +
  '{"fname":"Bill", "lname":"Peterson", "company":"HP"},' +
  '{"fname":"Peter", "lname":"Jacobs", "company":"Dell"}]';

var seperator = ',';
$('#json').html(jData);
$('#btnConvert').click(function() {
  ConvertToTable(jData);
});

function ConvertToTable(jData) {
  var arrJSON = typeof jData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(jData) : jData;
  var $table = $('<table/>');
  var $headerTr = $('<tr/>');

  for (var index in arrJSON[0]) {
    $headerTr.append($('<th/>').html(index));
  }
  $table.append($headerTr);
  for (var i = 0; i < arrJSON.length; i++) {
   var $tableTr = $('<tr/>');
    for (var index in arrJSON[i]) {
      $tableTr.append($('<td/>').html(arrJSON[i][index]));
    }
    $table.append($tableTr);
  }
  $('body').append($table);
}
```

Without the actual data, html and your implementation I cannot provide the actual working example,but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/sEwM6/) you can find a generic version

Another working Method [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tgtjcrqf/162/)